# Fuzzify existing ElasticSearch Java API query

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an existing ElasticSearch query that uses the Java API:

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = 
     boolQuery().should(queryStringQuery(theUsersQueryString)); 
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(...).setQuery(queryBuilder);
```

Now I want to **add fuzziness** to this, to allow minor misspellings to still return something to the user. My guess was that adding fuzziness parameters to the `QueryBuilders` object would be fruitful:

```
boolQuery().should(queryStringQuery(theUsersQueryString)
              .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
              .fuzzyMaxExpansions(4)
              .fuzzyPrefixLength(2));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I have so far been unable to find good documentation for this. For example, I have the string `John Deere` in my database. If I use the query string `deere` I get a match, but not if I use query strings `Deeree` or `Deeer`.

My question is: how should I correctly fuzzify my query?

Comment: Have you been [through this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness)?

Comment: @Val: Yes, I hoped my suggested code above would work as I've tried different combinations of values for the parameters but so far I've been unable to get fuzzy results, so I think there's something more to it related to the Java API.

Comment: Can you also show some sample data, the values you input into `theUsersQueryString` and the results you expect?

Comment: @Val: Question edited to include a simple example.

Comment: You're setting your fuzziness level to 1 but then you make queries with `Deeree` and `Deeer` which require 2 changes, since I see you're using a lowercase filter (i.e. you'd need to first do `deeree` and then chop off the last `e` into `deere`). Try setting `fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)`

Comment: actually scratch that (partially), I see you are also using the `fuzzy_prefix_length`, in that case fuzziness level 1 should work BUT you still need to make a lowercased query i.e. `deeree` since the first 2 letters much be an exact match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opted to create a new query rather than modifying my existing one.

```
MultiMatchQueryBuilder fuzzyMmQueryBuilder = multiMatchQuery(
                theUsersQueryString, "field1", "field2", ... , "fieldn").fuzziness("AUTO");
BoolQueryBuilder b = boolQuery().should(fuzzyMmQueryBuilder); 
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch(...).setQuery(b)... 
SearchResponse res = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

This query exhibits fuzzy behaviour.